How to use whats app business API as an authenticated chatbot
just starting out investigating using whats app as an authenticated channel.
Let's say the customer initiates a message, enters a username and password to login and can then access certain features. How do I know that the client has authenticated in subsequent calls? For example, is there something like a customer jwt or a session? Not really finding enough info in the documentation
